# Basis of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $V$ and $W$ are vectorial spaces of finite dimension, we denote $\mathscr{L}(V,W)$ like the set of all linear maps of $V$  in $W$. Let a linear map $L\in \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathbb{R}^{2})$ defined like $L(x,y)=(-x+y,2x+y)$ for each $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Find a basis $S=\{u_{1},u_{2}\}$  of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that
$$[L]_{S} := M_{L}^{S \rightarrow S}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Where $M_{L}^{S \rightarrow T}$ denote the matricial representation of the linear map $L\in \mathscr{L}(V,W)$ respective to the basis $S$ of $V$ and $T$ of $W$.

Let $u_{1}=(v,w)$,$u_{2}=(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. We have that the columns in the matricial representation are $L(u_{1})$ and $L(u_{2})$, so

$$L_{u_{1}}=(-v+w,2v+w)= (0,-3)^{T}$$
and
$$L_{u_{2}}=(-a+b,2a+b)=(-1,0)^{T}$$
Then, $v=w=-1$,$a=\frac{1}{3}$ and $b=-\frac{2}{3}$. Am I right?

Comment: You are mixing standard basis coordinates and coordinates with respect to $S=\{u_1, u_2\}$. The conditions should be $L(u_1) = 0 u_1 - 3 u_2$ (from the first column of $[L]_S$) and $L(u_2) = -1 u_1 + 0 u_2$ (from the second column of $[L]_S$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt you are forgetting that the columns of $[L]_S=M^{S\to S}_L$ are not the images of $u_1$ and $u_2$ but their coordinates with respect to $S$. Hence, the conditions on the basis $S=\{u_1, u_2\}$ given by $[L]_S$ should have been
\begin{align}
L(u_1) &= \phantom{-}0 u_1 - 3 u_2, \\
L(u_2) &= -1 u_1 + 0 u_2.
\end{align}
Setting $u_1=(v,w)^T$ and $u_2=(a,b)^T$ as you did, this translates to
\begin{align}
(-v+w,2v+w)^T &= (-3a, -3b)^T, \\
(-a+b,2a+b)^T &= (-v, -w)^T.
\end{align}
This is a homogeneous linear system of four equations and four variables:
\begin{align}
-v+w+3a\phantom{{}+3b} &= 0,\\
2v+w\phantom{{}+3a}+3b &= 0,\\
v\phantom{{}+w}-\phantom{3}a+\phantom{3}b &= 0,\\
w+2a+\phantom{3}b &= 0.
\end{align}
Row reduction yields that this is equivalent to
\begin{align}
v&=a-b,\\
w&=-2a-b.
\end{align}
In addition, $u_1$ and $u_2$ need to be linearly independent, which is equivalent to $vb-wa\neq 0$ and hence to $ab\neq 0$ (by substituting $v$ and $w$).

Picking $a=b=1$ we get $v=0$, $w=-3$ and indeed $u_1=(0,-3)^T$ and $u_2=(1,1)^T$ are linearly independent and yield
\begin{align}
L(u_1) &= L((\phantom{-}0,-3)^T) = (-3,-3)^T = -3 u_2, \\
L(u_2) &= L((\phantom{-}1,\phantom{-}1)^T) = (\phantom{-}0, \phantom{-}3)^T = -1 u_1.
\end{align}

Note that any other choice of non-zero $a,b$ also yields a valid solution.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that the linear map L can be represented by the matrix $A=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1\\2&1\end{matrix}\right)$ such that $L(x)=Ax$. Using your representation of $u_1=\left(\begin{matrix}v\\w\end{matrix}\right), u_2=\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\end{matrix}\right)$ to be the new basis, the following equations are gotten:

$\left(\begin{matrix}[Au_1]_\beta&[Au_2]_\beta\end{matrix}\right)= \left(\begin{matrix}0&-1\\-3&0\end{matrix}\right)$, where $\beta$ represents the new basis

This means

$\begin{cases}Au_1=0u_1+-3u_2\\ Au_2=-1u_1+0u_2\end{cases}$

Further elaborating,

$\begin{cases}w-v=-3a\\2v+w=-3b\\b-a=-v\\2a+b=-w\end{cases}$

$v=a-b, w=-2a-b$

Further, as mentioned in Cristoph's post, the basis vectors must be linearly independent. $u_1\ne cu_2\implies \frac v a\ne \frac w b \text{ or } bv-wa\ne0$

Picking $a=b=1,v=0,w=-3$, is a valid basis. **Note that this basis is neither orthogonal nor are the vectors normalized. If you attempt to normalize the vectors, the transformation will not work due to the contraints in the equations above.**

It is possible, however, to find an orthogonal basis. $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 1 2 (13+5\sqrt {13})\\\frac 1 2 (13-\sqrt {13})\end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix}\sqrt {13}\\\frac 1 2 (-13-3\sqrt {13})\end{matrix}\right)$ is one such possible orthogonal basis. It is not possible to find an orthonormal basis. In fact, it is not possible to find a normalized basis i.e. where both vectors have euclidean norm 1.

---

Test transformation in standard basis and new basis:

$\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1\\2&1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-2\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\0\end{matrix}\right)$

$\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1\\-3&0\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right)_\beta=\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\-3\end{matrix}\right)_\beta$

$\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\0\end{matrix}\right)=\left[\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\-3\end{matrix}\right)_\beta\right]_{\{e_1,e_2\}}$

Comment: I'm kind of lost when you said that $Au_{1}=0u_{1}-3u_{2}$ and $Au_{2}=-u_{1}+u_{2}$ like, why?
And if $u_{1}=(a-b, 2a-b),u_{2}=(a,b)$ they can be a basis, for example $a=b$ then $u_{1}=(0,1), u_{2}=(1,1)$ and they are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, or Did I misunderstood?

Comment: Because I have expressed Au_1 and Au_2 in the new basis. Yes that is a solution to the equations but it does not work for some reason when you try an example linear transformation using the standard basis and the new basis. I don’t know why :(

Comment: Your conclusion is false, the two matrices are in fact similar so there is a basis $S$ solving the problem.

Comment: I left out a minus sign,oops.